# urllib.request.urlopen: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '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@01bbe7-3.myshopify.com'

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

When I use `urlopen` on

```
https://78d32f2c60e08a06ef4438996e77f198: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@01bbe7-3.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/orders.json'
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 894, in _get_hostport
    port = int(host[i+1:])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '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@01bbe7-3.myshopify.com'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidhu/PycharmProjects/Code Tester/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(main(1))
  File "/Users/davidhu/PycharmProjects/Code Tester/main.py", line 6, in main
    with urlopen(url) as response:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1315, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout, **http_conn_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1406, in __init__
    super(HTTPSConnection, self).__init__(host, port, timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 856, in __init__
    (self.host, self.port) = self._get_hostport(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 899, in _get_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
http.client.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '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@01bbe7-3.myshopify.com'
```

I'm assuming its because of the colon between `'78d32f2c60e08a06ef4438996e77f198'` and `'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@01bbe7-3.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/orders.json'` but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Thanks

I'm unable to use `'import requests'` because IBM code engine won't compile with it.

Comment: You do realise that exposing what looks to be an access token to the whole world is not exactly a smart idea?

Comment: It is a place holder access token.

Comment: Colon `:` can be used to separate `address:port` and it seems it treats `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` as `port`. But as I remember colon can be also used to separate `user:password` in url `https://user:password@example.com/`. You may try to remove `user:password@` and keep only `https://example.com/` but it may have problem without `user` and `password`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.